# Figure not being typeset properly

Tags: graphics, floats, include, ieeetran

I'm writing a report with using the IEEE Transactions template, and the template itself includes an example figure:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{centering}
\textsf{A single column figure goes here}
\par\end{centering}
\caption{Captions go \emph{under} the figure}
\end{figure}
```

which is typeset very nicely as it should be.

However, when I replicate that, but also add in an image:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{centering}
\includegraphics{photo of stuff}
\par\end{centering}
\caption{things}
\label{fig:stuff}
\end{figure}
```

I get no image in the body of the text as it should be, but instead an ugly sprawl of all my figures on the following page:

[image: Bad code doing bad things]

Any ideas as to whats going wrong here and how to fix it would be greatly appreciate.
Thank you!

Comment: I guess that your image is too big. Try to use the option `\includegraphics[width=xxxcm]{photo of stuff}`.

Comment: @Sigur Please make that an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IEEE is known for having quite ridiculous things in their templates, which in some cases definitely should not be followed. You should IMHO try this:

```
\begin{figure}[tp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{yourfile}
\caption{Captions go \emph{under} the figure.}
\end{figure}
```

Remarks:

- I am strongly against `[h]` or `[H]` placement of figures, and I'm certainly not the only one. As well, I don't like `[b]`ottom figure
- `centering` is not an environment, just a command.
- `[width=\linewidth]` is a way how to make your graphics as wide as they can be.
- If you wanted a full-width graphics, you should be able to use `\begin{figure*}...\end{figure*}`. However, it necessarily moves the figure to the following page, so you might consider moving it in the code to get it where it should be.

Answer (score 4):

I'm almost sure that your image is too big.

Try to adjust the image width using an optional argument

```
\includegraphics[width=xxxcm]{photo of stuff}
```

where `xxx` is the desired length and `cm` is the unit. You can use other units, for example `mm`,  `pt` or `in`.

Also, you can set up the width equal to the line width using `width=\linewidth` (without unit, since that command already has one).

Comment: Please, make it into a complete example; also add that `\centering` should be used and not the inexistent `centering` environment.

Comment: @egreg, it is not necessary anymore. Other users had added similar answers. I guess that I'll delete mine.